# Need the hover state active for responsive layout

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a lovely hover state on my website with a box flying up with content, just at the base of the slideshow.  But I want that hover state with the content showing to be visible at all times for smaller screens. I'm not having any luck making this happen though.  The hover state is on an "a href".

Would this be done with CSS or with jQuery? And regardless, does anyone have a specific direction they can send me in for this?

Related (I think): Something on this homepage is making the screen scroll left/right. I haven't found a div that's causing this yet, but I'm clearly missing something.

[site](http://www.thepixelpixie.com)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you share the code that you are using right now for the current behavior, as well as describe anything you've tried to get the additional behavior working?

Comment: If you visit the site in question (link above) I think you'll find all the necessary code. If not, I'll be happy to post the styles I'm currently using.  In the meantime, this is what I'm using to try to make things work in mobile layout:

`code`@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) { 
 #services-test.segment .segment-content {margin-top: auto;overflow: visible;height: auto;}
 .traits-wrapper {height: auto;position: relative;}
 .trait-box {bottom: auto;width: 100%;margin-top: auto;height:auto;position: relative;}
 .trait-box figure {overflow: visible;}
 .trait-box dd {overflow: visible;}
}

Comment: (sorry...apparently the replies don't like hard returns, and I haven't quite figured out how to paste code properly...ugh)

Comment: Comments don't like code snippets much. You'll have more luck editing your original question to add code (you can use the code formatting tags to make it look nice). I haven't had a chance to look at your code yet -- will try to do so soon.

Answer (score 0):

[Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) should be what you're looking for:

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .my-class {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

This trivial example would hide `.my-class` when the screen width is <600px. What you'll want to do is define a rule that applies different CSS styling to your elements if the screen is below a specific boundary, and another rule that applies the "normal" styles if the screen size is above the boundary.
If you post your code, I can update the example with something more specific to your site.

Comment: See also: [How To Use CSS3 Media Queries To Create a Mobile Version of Your Website](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/), and [Use CSS media queries for responsiveness](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en)

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, if I'm understanding your answer correctly.  I know how to create media queries and have different CSS.  The issue here is that there is more than just a hover state consisting of a different font color or decoration.  In this instance, there are several divs, which in the normal state are collapsed and in the hover state expand and show content.  What I'm looking for is CSS (or maybe I'm needing some jQuery here instead? I don't know) that, in the mobile setting, makes ONLY the hover state the only state of those divs.

Comment: I gotcha -- I think I understand what you're trying to do. Yeah, it wouldn't be enough to just switch the hover state on or off in a media query. You may need to fall back to something like jQuery, but I _think_ this can be done with straight CSS. I still haven't had a chance to look at the code, sorry. I will take a look soon.